# What is a "view" table inside a mysql database?

Tags: mysql

I google'd the term when I first heard about this in mysql (the sakila sample mysql db has it), however the search results aren't really helping. Anyways, what exactly is it and is there a tutorial out there that explains it along with the advantages and disadvantages of using it?

Comment: [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/View_(database)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/View_(database))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A view is a named stored query that can be used in other queries as if it was a table.

Sometimes a view will present a sub-set of the rows in a table:

```
CREATE VIEW v1 AS
    SELECT Column1, Column2, ..., ColumnN
      FROM AnotherTable WHERE SomeColumn = 234;
```

Sometimes a view will present a sub-set of the columns in a table:

```
CREATE VIEW v2 AS
    SELECT Column2, Column3, Column5, Column7
      FROM AnotherTable;
```

You can also have more complex queries, with joins etc:

```
CREATE VIEW OrderInfo AS
    SELECT o.order_num, c.customer_num, c.customer_name,
           o.order_date, o.invoice_num, i.product_code, p.product_name
      FROM Orders     AS o
      JOIN Customers  AS c ON c.customer_num = o.customer_num
      JOIN OrderItems AS i ON i.order_num    = o.order_num
      JOIN Products   AS p ON p.product_code = i.product_code
```

Then users can write queries such as:

```
SELECT *
  FROM OrderInfo
 WHERE Order_Date BETWEEN DATE '2012-01-01' AND DATE '2012-01-31'
   AND Product_Code LIKE "%23491%";
```

without having to know how to join all the tables together.

You can also use views to control access to the data; the view definer's permissions may allow the user to access a table that would otherwise be barred to them.  You can also use views to provide backwards compatibility after modifying the schema of a database.  You change the names as well as the definitions of the tables in the new schema, but leave behind views that allow unmodified programs to continue to read the database as if the schema was unchanged.

Some views can be updated; others can't.  Which can and which can't depends on the DBMS.